# Create random submatrix of large matrix in python

Tags: python

I have the following code to create a random subset (of size examples) of a large set:

```
def sampling(input_set):
        tmp = random.sample(input_set, examples)
        return tmp
```

The problem is that my input is a large matrix, so input_set.shape = (n,m). However, sampling(input_set) is a list, while I want it to be a submatrix of size = (examples, m), not a list of length `examples` of vectors of size m.

I modified my code to do this:

```
def sampling(input_set):

    tmp = random.sample(input_set, examples)
    sample = input_set[0:examples]

    for i in range(examples):
        sample[i] = tmp[i]

    return sample
```

This works, but is there a more elegant/better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: if you are dealing with large matrices I suggest using numpy

Comment: How? Can you suggest some code?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy as follow to create a n x m matrix (assuming input_set is a list)

```
import numpy as np

input_matrix = np.array(input_set).reshape(n,m)
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking. input_set is a matrix, I want to extract a submatrix of (k,m) of the matrix (n,m), where k<n

Comment: I was answering your question about using numpy

Comment: You are saying I should do: def sampling(input_set):
        tmp = random.sample(input_set, examples) 
        return np.array(tmp).reshape(examples,m)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if i understand correctly the question you just want to drop the last couple of rolls (n - k) so:

> sample = input_matrix[:k - n]

must do the job for you.

Comment: No, I want to randomly pick k rows out of the n>k rows of the matrix. Random is key.

Comment: Ok then just permutate the matrix and get the first k rolls like:  `x=numpy.random.permutate(input_matrix) ` then `x[:k-n]`

Comment: Is permutate only permutating the rows? The elements in the row must stay the same

Comment: yes only the rows `>>> np.random.permutation([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if still interested in, but maybe you do something like this:

```
#select a random 6x6 matrix with items -10 / 10
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.randint(-10,10,(6,6))
print (mat)
#select a random int between 0 and 5
startIdx = np.random.randint(0,5)
print(startIdx)
#extracy submatrix (will be less than 3x3 id the index is out of bounds)
print(mat[startIdx:startIdx+3,startIdx:startIdx+3])
```